# I want to know how to add video control for jquery plugin?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, video, tags

I want to know how to  use or add video control for jquery plugin.

Here is my link: 
http://lotusvaluedevelopers.com/

Here is the code:

```
<script src="jsnew/jquery.vide.min.js"></script>
<div data-vide-bg="video/real.mp4" class="agile-banner"></div>
```

My Volume Control is missing.

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can make your own volume controle on the `<video>` tag. 
Get the `video` element and change the volume.

```
var instance = $('#yourElement').data('vide');

// Get video element of the background. Do what you want.
var video = instance.getVideoObject();

video.volume = 0.5;
```

Or add a classname to the plugin.

```
<div data-vide-bg="video/real.mp4" data-vide-options="className: myVideo" class="agile-banner"></div>
```

And set the volume of the `<video>` like so;

```
$('.myVideo').find('video')[0].volume = 0.5;
```

Comment: Hi, i have given the code , only first alert is working<script>
    var instance = $('#div').data('vide');
alert('ok');
var video = instance.getVideoObject();
alert(video.value);
video.volume = 0.5;  I have seen this link also I am not getting that, please guide me,

Comment: please check this line also var video = instance.getVideoObject();
alert(video);

Comment: `#div` selects an element with the `id='div'`. Try `var instance = $('.agile-banner').data('vide')`